# Malformed SQL string in Firebird with Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, firebird

I am working currently on a Laravel (Laravel version: 5.1.46 (LTS), PHP version: PHP 7.0.13) application that uses Firebird for database. I use iconv() to convert UTF-8 strings into Windows-1250 to save a record.
Since about 2 days it stopped working.

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'WINDOWS-1250', 'ékezet');
```

This is the code I use to convert it and than pass it to the following SQL query:

```
\DB::select(\DB::raw("UPDATE CIKK_LEIRASOK SET LEIRAS = '$leiras' WHERE VONALKOD = " . $product->VONALKOD));
```

But something went wrong and I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -104 Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Malformed string (SQL: UPDATE CIKK_LEIRASOK SET LEIRAS = '
>   ?kezet
>   ' WHERE VONALKOD = 1)

I googled about it but couldn't find anything and I have no clue what could be wrong.

Anyone more experienced in this subject?

Comment: What is your connection character set? Why are you concatenating values into a query string instead of using parameters? That is unsafe (SQL injection), and potentially the cause of the problem.

Comment: "Since about 2 days it stopped working." What hapend two days before? 
Whether the server version has not changed, for example to 2.5?

Comment: Actually we came up with something to fix the issue but the problem is still unsolved. No, all the environments are unchanged and we are currently checking the commits to see what could cause this. If we found the proper solution I will write as an answer. Thank you for your replies!